# Crontab - Django ERROR: /bin/sh: /usr/bin/crontab: File or directory does not exist

Tags: python, django, cron

I am working on a Django project that runs a crontab task to feed it's database.

The problem shows when I try to add the crontab job before running the django server:

COMMAND:

```
(venv) python manage.py crontab add
```

ERROR:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/crontab:  File or directory does not exist
  adding cronjob: (d99f11ab3bcd8ffb80a4a4f3b76cb35c) -> ('0,20,40 * * * *','data.cron.feed_database')
sh: /usr/bin/crontab:  File or directory does not exist
```

Django SETTINGS:

```
CRONJOBS = [
('0,20,40 * * * *', 'data.cron.feed_database'), 
]
```

Here are my crontab files:

crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/crontab

0,20,40 * * * * /home/mote/Desktop/CODE/ORION/djangorion/venv/bin/python /home/mote/Desktop/CODE/ORION/djangorion/manage.py crontab run d99f11ab3bcd8ffb80a4a4f3b76cb35c #django-cronjobs for orion
```

sudo crontab -e

```
"Empty"
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use `celerybeat` for your scheduled task needs

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue currently. Did you find any solution?
I have installed django-crontab[0.7.1] in my project specific venv and have searched a lot for the solution but nothing worked.